# Go non-blocking channel send, test-for-failure before attempting to send?

Tags: go, nonblocking, channel

Is there a way to test for failure of a go channel send without actually attempting the send? The standard non-blocking send is like so:

```
msg := "hi"
select {
    case messages <- msg:
        fmt.Println("sent message", msg)
    default:
        fmt.Println("no message sent")
    }
```

The problem is that I need to have "msg" ready to send in order to test the channel.

I would like to test to see if a send will fail in a way that does not require having "msg" ready for sending.

Comment: A send will either get buffered, blocked, timed out, or done.  Like JimB says: it's a data race to assume that you can't get blocked.  If you don't think that the sender is in the right state to send or the receiver in the right state to receive, then that's just an issue with the design of the protocol.  You could get state updates from the client about whether it thinks that it will accept the send.

Comment: So the answer is "No". There is no built in mechanism to do this. Thanks for verifying.

Comment: With the caveat that if you make the buffer large enough, and manage to never fill the buffer, you will never experience blocking in practice.  Never filling the buffer requires that the messages are always consumed in a timely manner; which is only guaranteed if the sender stops sending before the buffer is full.  If you think about it, then that's kind of like the sender "blocking" (refusing to send) because it knows that the receiver is full.

Answer (score 7):

That would do no good in the general case, since you then have a race. After generating msg the channel may no longer be ready to send.

If you need this pattern, you either need a second channel for signaling,

```
select {
    case <-ready:
        msg := generateMsg()
        messages <- msg
        fmt.Println("sent message", msg)
    default:
        fmt.Println("no message sent")
}
```

or you can use a [`sync.Cond`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Cond)