# How can I compute the message to be sent on a channel as late as possible?

Tags: go, nonblocking, channel

My scenario:

- I have a producer and a consumer. Both are goroutines, and they communicate through one channel.
- The producer is capable of (theoretically) generating a message at any time.
- Generating a message requires some computation.
- The message is somewhat time-sensitive (i.e. the older it is, the less relevant it is).
- The consumer reads from the channel occasionally. For the sake of this example, let's say the consumer uses a `time.Ticker` to read a message once every couple of seconds.
- The consumer would prefer "fresh" messages (i.e. messages that were generated as recently as possible).

So, the question is: **How can the producer generate a message as late as possible?**

---

Sample code that shows the general idea:

```golang
func producer() {
    for {
        select {
        ...
        case pipe <- generateMsg():
            // I'd like to call generateMsg as late as possible,
            // i.e. calculate the timestamp when I know
            // that writing to the channel will not block.
        }
    }
}

func consumer() {
    for {
        select {
        ...
        case <-timeTicker.C:
            // Reading from the consumer.
            msg <- pipe
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Full code (slightly different from above) is available at the Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/y0oCf39AV6P

---

One idea I had was to check if writing to a channel would block. If it wouldn't block, then I can generate a message and then send it. However…

- I couldn't find any way to test if writing to a channel would block or not.
- In the general case, this is a bad idea because it introduces a racing condition if we have multiple producers. In this specific case, I only have one producer.

---

Another (bad) idea:

```golang
func producer() {
    var msg Message
    for {
        // This is BAD. DON'T DO THIS!
        select {
        case pipe <- msg:
            // It may send the same message multiple times.
        default:
            msg = generateMsg()
            // It causes a busy-wait loop, high CPU usage
            // because it re-generates the message all the time.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you care about urgency, why use a ticker? Why not just read as soon as a message is ready?

Comment: IMO, Using channel and go-routine for this requirement defeats the purpose. This is an on-demand producer consumer problem. If you don't want to generate the message asynchronously ie producer shouldn't produce until a consumer wants it, then why do you want channel and go-routine in the first place. Why can't you just call the function directly and if generateMsg involves accessing critical memory then guard it with Mutex. Mutex is not evil, after all channel just wraps Mutex hides all dirty details as far I know.

Comment: I omitted from the scenario some other cases of the `select` statement. The producer is actually reading from other channel, computing some on-the-fly stats, and serving those stats to the consumer. The consumer only needs to display the stats once per second or so, thus, it only needs to consume once per second. But maybe this is too convoluted like you say.

Comment: @DenilsonSáMaia: So let it calculate the stats once per second. No need for a consumer/producer pattern, goroutines, or channels.

Comment: Agreed. This seems like a case for shared memory that the "producer" updates on its schedule and the "consumer" reads on its schedule, with a mutex lock to avoid races.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to completely change the logic? The producer, when it's ready to produce a message, merely sends some sort of a token to the consumer which means "I am ready to roll". The consumer then acquires the token and either explicitly asks the producer to do the work or _does the work itself._ In the simplest case the producer could send a function value, which the consumer would then call. Sure, in this case one should think through the synchronization—if needed—since the consumer will initiate doing the work in an indeterminate moment of time.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29016251) (for [Go non-blocking channel send, test-for-failure before attempting to send?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29016118)) suggests using a second channel to send a signal from the consumer to the producer:

1. Consumer wants to get a message (e.g. after receiving a tick from `timer.Ticker`).
2. Consumer sends a signal through a side channel to the producer goroutine. (So, for this side channel, the producer/consumer roles are reversed).
3. Producer receives the signal from the side channel.
4. Producer starts computing the real message.
5. Producer sends the message through the main channel.
6. Consumer receives the message.

Comment: This seems over-complicated to me. In fact, the entire scenario seems like unnecessary complexity, for no gain.